# Java: Really simple scatter plot utility

Tags: java, charts, scatter-plot

I know there are many comparisons of java plotting libraries out there, but I'm not finding what I need. I just want a mind-numbingly simple toolkit that creates images of scatterplots from a set of coordinates. No GUI, no interaction, no fancy display, just a basic XY coordinate system with points.

It wouldn't be the end of the world to use something that offers a lot more functionality than I need, but I'd rather not. Do you know of anything like what I'm looking for?

Comment: you should try this, it is not 100% accurate, but should do the job [simple-scatter-plot](https://code.google.com/p/simple-scatter-plot/)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you looked at [JFreeChart](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/)?  While it can do some very advanced things, it also does the simple as well.  Shown below is a screenshot of its scatter plot capability.

[image]
<sub>(source: [jfree.org](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/images/ScatterPlotDemo1.png))</sub>

Answer (score 3):

I looked around at what existed, and realized that jcckit is technically pretty good, but just lacks a simple wrapper around it to make it easy to use.

So I forked it and made a really simple wrapper.  Here's how to use:

```
import static easyjcckit.QuickPlot.*;

double[] xaxis = new double[]{0,1,2,3,4,5};
double[] yvalues = new double[]{0,1,4,9,16,25};
scatter( xaxis, yvalues ); // create a plot using xaxis and yvalues
double[] yvalues2 = new double[]{0,1,2,3,4,5};
addScatter( xaxis, yvalues2 ); // create a second plot on top of first

System.out.println("Press enter to exit");
System.in.read();
```

As well as scatter plots, you can freely add lines to the same axes if you wish using 'addPlot' and 'plot'.

Here is the code: https://bitbucket.org/hughperkins/easyjcckit

Comment: Is it possible to set different color on the different plots/sets?

Answer (score 2):

You an use a custom JPanel to draw your data(not tested, but you get the idea...)

```
private List<Point2D> data=(...);

JPanel pane=new JPanel()
{
protected paintComponent(Graphics2D g)
{
super.paintComponent(g);
int minx=(...),miny=(...),maxx=(...),maxy=(...);
for(Point2D p: data)
 {
 int x=((p.getX()-minx)/(maxx-minx))*this.getWidth();
 int y=((p.getY()-miny)/(maxy-miny))*this.getHeight();
 g.drawLine(x-5,y,x+5,y);
 g.drawLine(x,y-5,x,y+5);
 }
}
pane.setOpaque(true);
(...)
anotherComponent.add(pane);
(...)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Also you could check [Simple Java Plot](http://yuriy-g.github.io/simple-java-plot/). Minimal example (no options):

```
Plot plot = Plot.plot(null).
    // setting data
    series(null, Plot.data().
        xy(1, 2).
        xy(3, 4), null);
// saving sample_minimal.png
plot.save("sample_minimal", "png");
```